# How do I extract specific values from a dataset in order to predict the growth?

Tags: tensorflow, regression, google-colaboratory, linear-regression

I'm trying to extract the values from the columns Y1993 to Y2013 for each row, and using linear regression in order to predict the growth in the amount of crop output. Column one is the area (country), Column two is the Item (which crop it is), Column 3 is the Element (whether it is food or feed), Column 4 is the Unit (1000 tonnes), and the rest of the columns are the crop output for different crops in different areas throughout 1993 to 2013.

I tried to extract the values of the columns using different code on other websites and Stack Overflow but it didn't work for me. I expected that the program would accurately predict the future growth of each crop, but it crashed or made graphs based on different variables (Y1993 and Y2013 instead of future crop output).

[Crop dataset (head)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3p32.png)`Don't know how to extract`

Maybe I can use the index value on the left (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc) to indicate which rows I'm using and then extract values from the columns Y1993 to Y2013 to predict the growth but I don't know how to do that. Help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.